# Simple regex between brackets

Tags: java, regex, decimal, brackets, tasker

Sorry for being a noob but I have been searching the forums for hours but no luck so huge thanks if you can help.

I'm using Tasker which I believe uses a java flavor of regex.

I have random data for example: `blah blah blah 6521 (3.2g) 345 (8g) 34 etc...`

Between the brackets there's only ever a just a single digit or a single digit followed by a single decimal digit, with the `(` and `g)` always being constant, I simply need to extract numbers like:

`3.2` & `8` into their array which Tasker will do.

What I would think should work, is not working properly:

> \d+.\d+|\d+

It produces all the numbers instead of just those between `(` and `g)`

Any pointers anyone?

Much appreciated all!

EDIT:typos

Comment: I think you have to escape the parenthesis, they're grouping operators otherwise.

Comment: Make the `.` and trailing number optional, `\d+(\.\d)?`. I don't know java but that regex should capture the numerical values you want.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatly this produces other numbers that arent in brackets with 'g'. I have edited the orginal data for clarification. Cheers again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following pattern:
`(?<=\()\d+\.?\d?(?=g\))`

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hnGnpl/3)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatly this produces other numbers that arent in brackets with 'g'. I have edited the orginal data for clarification. Cheers again!

Comment: Hi @binvius: I have updated the pattern based on your sample input. Please check if it fits your needs.

Comment: Quinn, you beautiful beautiful beast - you've only gone and cracked it! Dozens of mere mortals have fought but only you have conquered. I cannot thank you enough for doing a lovely thing for a random stranger. Keep up the good work and all the best for the future

Answer (score 2):

To match the numbers, use digit(s) folowed by optional dot-then-digit(s), preceded by an open bracket:

```
(?<=\()\d+(\.\d+)?(?=g\))
```

The expression `(?<=\()` is a *look behind* and means the preceding char must be `(`, but doesn’t consume the it as part of the match.

Similarly, `(?=g\))` asserts the the next chars are `g)`. You probably don’t need `(?=g\))`, but it tightens up the match.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatly this produces other numbers that arent in brackets with 'g'. I have edited the orginal data for clarification. Cheers again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.*; 

public class YourClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create a list to store the result */
        List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+).(\\d+)|(\\d+)").matcher("(3.2g) (8g)");

        /* Add the results to list */
        while (m.find()) {
           allMatches.add(m.group());
        }

        /* Print out the result */
        for(int i=0; i< allMatches.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(allMatches.get(i)+" ");
        }

    }
}
```

You can replace `(3.2g) (8g)` with your `String` value. 
You can also cast list into array, if needed.

Comment: Cheers for this. I tried just the regex part but with no luck. With many more hours trying, Im starting to think that this may not even be possible with regex. Thanks anyone else if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

So far and aside from the hundreds I've tried, all of the very kind suggestions on this page have produced all the numbers `6521 3.2 345 8 34` from the data string, instead of just those between `(` and `g)`  which would only result in`3.2` & `8`

```
\d+.\d+|\d+

\d+(\.\d)?

\d+(\.\d+)?

\d+\.\d+|\d+

("(\\d+).(\\d+)|(\\d+)")

(\\d+).(\\d+)|(\\d+)
```

Perhaps it is unfortunately not possible or maybe, although I always believed it was very advanced, Tasker doesn't like something about it.

If any Regex wizards feel like giving this a 30 second crack, I would be eternally grateful.

Thanks again!

Comment: This should be an edit to your original post, not an answer. It doesn't seem to answer your question and is buried under other people's answers :)